# Is Zxing providing UPC barcodes coordinates on the screen?

Tags: zxing

I need to know where the barcode is positioned on the screen. I need it for UPC barcodes or, more in genera, for 1D Barcodes.

So far the ZXResult resultPoints array seem to provide only few (clue) points on the same scanning line and not the coordinates of the barcode rectangle.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. It does not operate by detecting the whole rectangle since it's unnecessary and slow. It scans by line. When detected it can tell you two points on the line -- the middle of the guard pattern at the start and end.

If you want to find the whole rectangle you need to do it yourself, though these points are a clue about where to search. Look at `MonochromeRectangleDetector` or `WhiteRectangleDetector` in the project, which can find a barcode-like rectangle.